# When I enable Service Worker I get a lot of CORS errors on my site

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, service-worker

A snapshot of my site can be viewed via this link: [Netlify App](https://6569a97b9c39e00008034971--n-source-kmar.netlify.app/)

After opening this page in a browser that supports Service Worker, waiting for Service Worker to install, and then manually refreshing the page (don not disabling caching), you'll find that most of the images on the page won't load, and there will be quite a lot of errors like the one below in the console:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://image.kmar.top/cover/bangumis.png!/fw/477' from origin 'https://6569a97b9c39e00008034971--n-source-kmar.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This error is usually due to the fact that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` information is not properly configured on the server side, but I have configured that header on the server.

If I refresh the page with `ctrl F5`, check "Disable Cache" in Developer Tools, or check "Network Bypass" (i.e., skip the Service Worker's `fetch` event) in Developer Tools, then the images will load normally after refreshing the page, and there will be no CORS errors in the background.

I am loading the resources in the Service Worker with the following code:

```js
fetch('https://xxx', {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'same-orgin'
})
```

It doesn't make sense that a CORS error should occur, but it does, and I get the same problem when I let other people open my site. I'm really wondering why I don't get CORS errors when I disable browser caching, and I'm not sure what's wrong.

In the end I chose to skip these links in my service worker to avoid the CORS error, but this wasn't a permanent solution, and I've made my service worker available for others to use as well, and I'd like to be able to figure out what's going on so that I don't cause other people's sites to get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Finally there is something wrong with the server configuration, the browser accesses the file without the origin header, my server adds the cors information based on the origin header, I changed the server configuration and it's fine.

Comment: any comment or doc to what you did specifically would be great